# Xdebug on Symfony built-in server

Tags: symfony, xdebug

Is it possible to set Xdebug on Symfony built-in server as is used in Apache? I haven`t found any tutorial on the web and I don't know if it's possible, or I have to use Apache to develop in order to use Xdebug.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Xdebug does not care whether you run the built-in Symfony server (which is really the built-in PHP web server), or Apache. As long as PHP runs somewhere, Xdebug can work.

Comment: Just as a clarification, the latest "Symfony built-in web server" is no longer a wrapper for `php -S`, but a go executable that connects to an independent PHP process. (The answer is still correct, of course, it's just a matter of the OP finding which PHP runtime they are using and configure Xdebug accordingly).